# Javascript interface with android not working

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to pass variables to JavaScript from Android. When the map button is clicked, it opens this class with the following `onCreate` method:

```
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    setMyWebviewSettings(myWebView.getSettings());

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    double[] coordinates = setCoordinates(extras);

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(coordinates), "JSInterface");

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.0.32:8887/services/maps/examples/basic-example.htm");
}
```

Here is the `setMyWebviewSettings` method:

```
private void setMyWebviewSettings(WebSettings MyWebviewSettings){
    MyWebviewSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    MyWebviewSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
}
```

Then here is `JavaScriptInterface`:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    double lat;
    double lon;
    double pan;

    JavaScriptInterface(double[] coordinate) {
        this.lat = coordinate[0];
        this.lon = coordinate[1];
        this.pan = coordinate[2];
    }

    public double getLatValue() {
        return lat;
    }

    public double getLonValue() {
        return lon;
    }

    public double getPanValue() {
        return pan;
    }
}
```

Here is `setCoordinates` method:

```
private double[] setCoordinates(Bundle extras) {

    double[] coordinates = new double[3];

    coordinates[0] = 45.9049;
    coordinates[1] = 13.3177;
    coordinates[2] = 15;

    if (extras != null) {
        coordinates[0] = extras.getDouble("lat");
        coordinates[1] = extras.getDouble("lon");
        coordinates[2] = extras.getDouble("pan");
    }
    return coordinates;
}
```

Everything works except that it doesn't load the map. The `Bundle extras` is `Null`. what to do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are passing the values when creating the intent that starts the second activity. If the bundle is null then it means they aren't contained in the intent.

Comment: Yes, I found that I am passing an empty Bundle. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)), I think that maybe you are missing the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
   @JavascriptInterface
   public double getLatValue() {
      return lat;
   }

   @JavascriptInterface
   public double getLonValue() {
      return lon;
   }

   @JavascriptInterface
   public double getPanValue() {
      return pan;
   }
}
```

Comment: Although it wasn't the answer, but it helped a lot. Thanks